# Failed to add i915 component masters (-19) Kali Linux 2.0 setup

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux

While attempting to setup Kali Linux 2.0 as a dual boot with windows on my laptop. I encountered that error after entering graphic install. Any ideas?

Laptop: Asus gl552vw

Tried:
-Using another Pendrive
-Remaking the bootable pendrive with PowerISO